# ERROR: device '' not found. Skipping fsck (can't boot)

Tags: boot, initramfs, manjaro

I have a Manjaro Linux installation and after a `pacman - syu` update (potentially updating the kernel) , and restarting my computer, I get the following error message after grub:

```
[ 4.896409] Initramfs unpacking
failed: read error  
:: running early hook [udev]  
:: running early hook [lvm2] 
:: running hook [udev] 
:: Triggering uevents... 
:: running hook [plymouth] 
:: Loading plymouth... done
:: running hook [plymouth-encrypt] 
:: running hook [resume] 
ERROR: resume: no device specified for hibernation
ERROR: device '' not found. Skipping fsck
:: mounting '' on real root
You are now being dropped into an emergency shell. 
sh: can't access tty; job control turned off
[rootfs  ] #
```

At the shell, if I type, no letters are appearing on the screen, leading me to believe it is not registering keyboard input.  Also note that my hard drive is encrypted.  At grub, I have the option for Manjaro Linux kernel 4.9.34-1 x64 and 4.9.33-1-rt23 x64 (and respective fallback initramfs) which I have tried. If there is any more information that I can provide, I am willing to.

Comment: I have a similar problem. Have you been enable to resolve this?

Comment: check and edit fstab file... and remove the mounting entry if any for such device ...

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, when trying to bring up a new machine in Arch.  My problem was that my initramfs was missing all modules, but you seem to have some, so it's not the identical problem, but I think the solution will be the same.

See your first error is there in the second line of your posted log:

> failed: read error

See how it's failing to read your initramfs, so it looks like that got corrupted somehow, and it's given up reading it.  You need to rebuild your initramfs.

I did that like this, after I'd booted to a rescue DVD, and mounted my system in /mnt and chrooted into that:

> mkinitcpio -p linux

You're best off updating your grub.cfg at this point, I think (though I'm new to grub, so don't quote me on that).  This, from the same environment should do that for you:

> grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg

When I ran that I saw new messages about it finding my kernel and initramfs, so I think I'd managed to run it with an incorrectly populated /boot folder last time.  You may not have that problem, but if you've no hand-crafted edits you want to keep, I'd regenerate it just out of habit.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe grub is not installed properly. The step

```
# grub-install /dev/sda
```

is missed.